# How grab contents of div based on text of within previous div

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="field field-name-field-entry-level field-type-text field-label-above">
      <div class="field-label">Entry level</div>
    <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">
              <div class="">Level 1</div>
```

I am trying to grab the text "Level 1" based on the div above having the words "Entry Level".

I am trying variations of:

```
//div[@class='field-label'][text()='Entry Level']/following-sibling::div[2]
```

But can't seem to grab it for some reason.

Comment: Your HTML code sample seem to be incomplete. Update it with closing tags

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
# for exact match
//div[text()='Entry level']/following-sibling::*/div/div
//div[@class='field-label' and text()='Entry level']/following-sibling::*/div/div
(//div[@class='field-label' and text()='Entry level']/following-sibling::*//div)[2]

# for contain
//div[contains(text(),'Entry level')]/following-sibling::*/div/div
```